# Baud rate Arduino/Linux

Tags: serial, linux, baud-rate, rs232

I'm trying to communicate some numbers between a Linux program and my Ardunino Uno. To this end I wrote a C++ program which somehow contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a,b;
a = 1;
b = 2000;

File* serial = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0","w");
fprintf(serial,"%d,%d\n",a,b);
fclose(serial);
```

Now out of standards I guess, the baud rate is 9600 bit/s. If I use `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200` I can change the baude rate of that port to 115200 bit/s. However the communication does not work anymore. My arduino program waiting for `number,number` does not show any action to the same code as before. Oh, and in the Arduino program of course I changed the code to `serial.begin(115200);`.

How can I change the baude rate in such a setup? If it is a concern, I'm using Ubuntu and an Arduino Uno.

Comment: Also take into account that default settings may mean that opening the port resets the Arduino.  There will then typically be a brief delay before the bootloader hands over control to your sketch, so anything your program writes immediately after a port-open-reset will be lost and never seen by your sketch.  You can add a delay before writing your data or change the modem control signal settings to not trigger a reset (or at least not trigger one on *subsequent* port openings).  Even more reliable might be to open the port bidirectional and wait to receive a ready prompt from the sketch.

Comment: Thanks for the highly relevant hint! Could you maybe elaborate more on how the reset trigger is called? Or where I can disable it?
At the time beeing a bidirectional opening is more hasstle, than service, but I'll have it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I tried it again with exactly the same settings and it worked. It seems, as if Linux uses the settings of ssty, when referring to the "file" of a serial connection.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Settings do tend to persist.  You may want to reboot your system and see that it *still* works, and isn't only working because of settings set up by some program you ran during your experiments.  Programs that use the serial port are split in behavior - some leave their settings behind, others (at least on a normal exit) will set things back however they found them.  Also be aware that the necessary difference from bootup defaults may be more than baud rate - there is a lot about word format and character mapping and special casing to contemplate, too.

Comment: Thanks, using stty -F /dev/.. I tried to verify the baud rate after a reboot, but it is reset to 9600 baud. I didn't use any other related programs to change settings. So I guess I have to write a script to change the rate at bootup.

Answer (score 3):

Setting baud rates in a C program isn't a trivial task. You need to use the low-level `open()` instead of `fopen()` and act on the returned file descriptor with `ioctl()` or `tcsetattr() / tcgetattr()`.  The former method allows the setting of non-standard baud rates while the latter only allows specific baud rates to be used.

I wrote a C++ class to deal with it all for me a while back. You are welcome to examine the methodology and/or steal whatever bits of it you like to use in your own program.

- https://github.com/majenkotech/SerialPort